# An application can display multiple icons in Android

Tags: android

I designed one Application in Android. When i upload this Application on device, it will display three icons of that application.[image]

Which part of Android Manifest File is responsible to display the icon.Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to confuse your users?

Comment: No..I dont understand why it occurs?..I just wrote my code and test this first time

Comment: is it in your manifest 3 times?

Comment: Which part is responsible to display the icon on device?..Any idea?

Comment: copy paste your manifest here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and **remove the launcher intent from all activities but one**

Only a single activity - the one you want opened when the user clicks the homescreen icon - should have the following intent filter:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

See your AndroidManifest file. How many activities you have with next code:

```
  <intent-filter>
   <action   android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

You must have 3 activity for this case.

Also this is may be last package name of your project before you rename it.

Answer (score 0):

See here Manifest file

```
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

And

```
                 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```